# How to count number of elements in specific row?

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Count number of values in matrix within given range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016236/count-number-of-values-in-matrix-within-given-range)

I have the following matrix

```
A=[ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7;
    3 4 5 6 8 9 1;
    3 4 2 5 6 7 8]
```

How to find out how many element there are in the first row, which have a value in the range `>2 & <6`?

Comment: Just do the exact same as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016236/count-number-of-values-in-matrix-within-given-range), but then on `A(1,:)` instead of `A(:)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well what you mean with **account**, if you want to `find` elements that meet your criteria:

```
B = A(1,:)
find(B > 2 & B < 6)
```

or in one line:

```
find(A(1,:) > 2 & A(1,:) < 6)
```

You must know also that `find` gives you the ***indices***, not the actual elements, of the array that satisfy the logical expression given.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think in terms of matrices, using vectorized computations. (Using find is not a good solution here, since it is not vectorized to operate independently on the rows.)

First, what happens if you try the test, A > 2, in MATLAB? TRY IT!

```
A=[ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7;
    3 4 5 6 8 9 1;
    3 4 2 5 6 7 8];

>> A > 2
ans =
     0     0     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     0
     1     1     0     1     1     1     1
```

MATLAB generates a logical array, true where an element of A was greater than 2. Similarly, if we type A < 6, we get another logical array.

```
>> A < 6
ans =
     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     1
     1     1     1     1     0     0     0
```

What if we combine the two ops into one expression?

```
>> (A > 2) & (A < 6)
ans =
     0     0     1     1     1     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
     1     1     0     1     0     0     0
```

Ok, so this array tells us where both sub-expressions were true. Note that we can operate on a logical array using sum and other arithmetic ops.

```
>> sum((A > 2) & (A < 6),2)
ans =
     3
     3
     3
```

So the above expression counts the number of elements that satisfy your goal for each row, and it will be quite fast. Learn to use MATLAB as it should be used. Your code will get better.