# Matlab performance: comparison slower than arithmetic

Tags: performance, matlab, operators, octave, jit

A while back I provided an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016236/count-number-of-values-in-matrix-within-given-range/12017205#12017205).

Objective: count the number of values in this matrix that are in the `[3 6]` range:

```
A = [2 3 4 5 6 7;
     7 6 5 4 3 2]
```

I came up with 12 different ways to do it:

```
count = numel(A( A(:)>3 & A(:)<6 ))      %# (1)
count = length(A( A(:)>3 & A(:)<6 ))     %# (2)
count = nnz( A(:)>3 & A(:)<6 )           %# (3)
count = sum( A(:)>3 & A(:)<6 )           %# (4)

Ac = A(:);
count = numel(A( Ac>3 & Ac<6 ))          %# (5,6,7,8)
%# prevents double expansion
%# similar for length(), nnz(), sum(),
%# in the same order as (1)-(4)

count = numel(A( abs(A-(6+3)/2)<3/2 ))   %# (9,10,11,12)
%# prevents double comparison and & 
%# similar for length(), nnz(), sum()
%# in the same order as (1)-(4)
```

So, I decided to find out which is fastest. Test code:

```
A = randi(10, 50);
tic
for ii = 1:1e5

    %# method is inserted here

end
toc
```

results (best of 5 runs, all in seconds):

```
%# ( 1): 2.981446
%# ( 2): 3.006602
%# ( 3): 3.077083
%# ( 4): 2.619057
%# ( 5): 3.011029
%# ( 6): 2.868021
%# ( 7): 3.149641
%# ( 8): 2.457988
%# ( 9): 1.675575
%# (10): 1.675384
%# (11): 2.442607
%# (12): 1.222510
```

So it seems that `count = sum(( abs(A(:)-(6+3)/2) < (3/2) ));` is the fastest way to go here...

I trade one `<` with two divisions, an addition and an `abs`, and the execution time is **less than half**! Does anyone have an explanation for why this is?

The JIT compiler probably replaces the divisions/additions with a single value in memory, but there's still the `abs`...Branch misprediction then? Seems silly for something as simple as this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `A(:)>3 & A(:)<6` expression needs to evaluate two conditions, whereas the `abs(A(:)-(6+3)/2) < 3/2)` evaluates one only one.

For very tight compute intensive loops this makes a lot of difference. Even without branch mispredictions, branching in itself is relatively costly. That's why, for instance, [*loop unrolling*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding) works as an optimization technique.

Comment: *three* if statements? Doesn't this sort of thing get JITed to the equivalent of `if (element[i] < 6) && (element[i] > 3){...}`? Even if this is not the case, then it would be maximum *two* `if`-statements, no? `if (element[i]<6) return true; return false; ...&&...if (element[i]>6) return true; return false;`

Comment: By the way, `&&` is short-circuit, but works on scalars only. I used `&` because that's the way to do it with arrays. Strange, but that's the way it is. I expect that internally they're the same, but the syntax is anyway different. Shall I edit your post?

Comment: Really I did not know branching was so costly...I'll remember that for the future. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, feel free to change it. I am not fluent in matlab and missed that ;-)