# Efficient method for finding elements in MATLAB matrix

Tags: matlab, find, matrix-indexing

I would like to know how can the bottleneck be treated in the given piece of code.

```
%% Points is an Nx3 matrix having the coordinates of N points where N ~ 10^6
Z = points(:,3)
listZ = (Z >= a & Z < b); % Bottleneck
np = sum(listZ); % For later usage
slice = points(listZ,:);
```

Currently for `N ~ 10^6`, `np ~ 1000` and `number of calls to this part of code = 1000`, the bottleneck statement is taking around 10 seconds in total, which is a big chunk of time compared to the rest of my code.

[image: Profiling Results]

Some more screenshots of a sample code for only the indexing statement as requested by @EitanT

[image: Profiling for sample code]
[image: Profiling for sample code]

Comment: Are you sure it's the bottleneck (can you show the profiling results)? And what is `num_calls` anyway?

Comment: @EitanT Yes I have checked it through the MATLAB profiler itself and this statement is indeed the bottleneck

Comment: @EitanT I've added the profiling result

Comment: Thanks. Can you reduce your code to a minimal example that recreates this behaviour? (Including the input data and the loop that invokes this part of code multiple times)

Comment: I could be wrong but doesn't `listZ = (Z >= a & Z < b);` need to be [`&&`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operators.html#f0-39129) instead of just [`&`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorselementwise.html)?

Comment: @EitanT There, I check my actual program values, updated them in the question and also posted profiles of programs operating in the same order.

Comment: @KronoS - No that doesn't work here.

Comment: @KronoS - `&` is an element-wise `AND` operation, `&&` is the logical AND short-circuit operator.

Comment: @DangKhoa Ya I was wrong... However I just tested this on my machine and it completed in [less than a half second](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qSUYJ.png).  Are you sure that this is the code that is giving you issues?

Comment: What kind of CPU do you have? And what does `feature accel` give you?

Comment: Why do you have this embedded in a for loop?

Comment: @KronoS: Except that you tested only `1e6` elements, while the OP is doing `1e9`...So, you'd take about 44 seconds.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis - I am running this on a Core i7 740QM and feature accel is 'on' already.

Comment: @KronoS You have generated integers, not doubles, and the looping in the sample code is done to simulate what happens in he real code as shown in the first screenshot - In real the loop runs for different slices possible in a data (I hope the variable names in the first screenshot) are clear enough

Comment: Related: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137233/matlab-performance-comparison-slower-than-arithmetic).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the equality on one side is not important you can reformulate it to a one-sided comparison and it gets one order of magnitude faster:

```
Z = rand(1e6,3);
a=0.5; b=0.6;
c=(a+b)/2;
d=abs(a-b)/2;
tic
for k=1:100,
    listZ1 = (Z >= a & Z < b); % Bottleneck
end
toc

tic
for k=1:100,
    listZ2 = (abs(Z-c)<d);
end
toc

isequal(listZ1, listZ2)
```

returns

```
Elapsed time is 5.567460 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.625646 seconds.

ans =

     1
```

Comment: Ah! That reminds me of [something I asked in the past](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137233/matlab-performance-comparison-slower-than-arithmetic). Indeed, I think this is the way to go.

Comment: This is good! Although I'm getting a little less than an order of magnitude in the actual program maybe because of the complexity of the rest of the code - but still I think something more could be done.

Comment: See also the accepted answer to [this recent C programming question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17095534/1165522).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the worst case:

- element-wise `&` is not short-circuited internally
- the comparisons are single-threaded

You're doing `2*1e6*1e3 = 2e9` comparisons in ~10 seconds. That's ~200 million comparisons per second (~200 MFLOPS).

Considering you can do some [1.7 GFLops on a single core](http://browser.primatelabs.com/geekbench2/1217520), this indeed seems rather low.

Are you running Windows 7? If so, have you checked your power settings? You are on a mobile processor, so I expect that by default, there will be some low-power consumption scheme in effect. This allows windows to scale down the processing speed, so...check that.

Other than that....I really have no clue.

Comment: Nice point to note there - but I've made sure about the power plan - and during computation turbo boost is also kicking in since this is running single threaded. I shall check my CPU's throughput through geekbench and let you know though.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing something like this:

```
for i = 1:1000
    x = (a >= 0.5);
    x = (x < 0.6);
end
```

I found it to be faster than:

```
for i = 1:1000
    x = (a >= 0.5 & a < 0.6);
end
```

by about 4 seconds:

```
Elapsed time is 0.985001 seconds. (first one)
Elapsed time is 4.888243 seconds. (second one)
```

I think the reason for your slowing is the element wise `&` operation.

Comment: Ya I see what you mean now.