# Compare Values in Array on Specific Indexes in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, compare

how to Compare Values in Array on Specific Indexes in Matlab? 
Suppose:

```
A= [2 2 3 3 3  4 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 8 8]
```

so i want to Find that 
on index **2,3,4,5,6** values or same or not ?

**Note: Index can be Dynamically Entered.**
Number(length) of Values in Array also can be changed..

Comment: You want to check rather all values on dynamically entered index are same or not? So your result would be a boolean (true / false). Is that right?

Comment: Values of Array will Changed Every time if I will Execute the Code. Just like Random, 
And I Just Want to compare Values of Array with Each other on Specific Indexes. That Index are Dynamic. 
Like May be I can check 4 indexes Values, next time Requirement may be 5 indexes Values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if they are all equal: use `diff` to subtract pairs of values, and then check if all those differences are 0.

```
A = [2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 8 8];
ind = [2 3 4 5 6];
result = ~any(diff(A(ind)));
```

This is faster than using `unique`. With `A` and `ind` as in your example,

```
>> tic
for cont = 1:1e5
    result = ~any(diff(A(ind)));
end
toc

tic
for cont = 1:1e5
    result=numel(unique(A(ind)))==1;
end
toc

Elapsed time is 0.371142 seconds.
Elapsed time is 4.754007 seconds.
```

Comment: I just Confirmed. It So Fast. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hey this should do the trick:

```
A= [2 2 3 3 3  4 4 4 5 5 6 6 7 8 8];

B= [1,3,5];

C=A(B);
result=numel(unique(C))==1;
```

Here `A` is your data. 
`B` is the index vector.
`C` contains the elements corresponding to the index vector.
`result` is 1 if all values were the same and 0 otherwise.

You can even "shorten" the code further by joining the two line:

```
result=numel(unique(A(B)))==1;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways, it depends on your taste.

For example, if the variable `indexing` contain the corresponding indexes:

```
unique(A(indexing));
```

will give you a vector with the unique elements in the sub-vector `A(indexing)`. Then you just need to check the length:

```
length(unique(A(indexing))) == 1
```

I would avoid the use of numel when the function length is available (it is much more clearer what you are trying to achieve).

Other option is to compare the first element to the rest of the element in the sub-vector:

```
sub_vector = A(indexing);
all(sub_vector == sub_vector(1));
```

The second option assumes that the sub-vector will never be empty!

Comment: Nice additional solution with `all()`, but what i don't understand ist why would you avoid to use `numel`? `numel` stands for number of elements which is much more clearer than `length`. Because that could be missunderstood to be the number of digits. E.g. `length(20)` could be missunderstood as `2` by someone not that fit in matlab. At least my opinion :D

Comment: I prefer `length` because its functionality is more consistent with other programming languages, hence clearer for newcomers or beginners. I guess it is a matter of style :) Taking a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016236/count-number-of-values-in-matrix-within-given-range) I can see that `length` is slightly slower than `numel`, yet I still favor `length` over `numel` in my code.

Comment: What if I want to Compare Last 5 elements. and Length of Array A is still not Fix ??

Comment: You need a bit of matlab magic: define `tmp = 1:7;` to get the subvector of the last five elements you could do `sub_vector = tmp(end-4:end);` Or you could also calculate the length of the original vector and from there get the last 5 elements.